# submit form outside Html.BeginForm MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.beginform, url-action

I want to be able to submit a form outside the Html.BeginForm, this is what i have and is working inside the form..

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="previous" formaction='@Url.Action("Previous", "StudentTest")' >previous </button>
```

I looked around and found a solution: give ur Html.BeginForm a name like this:

```
Html.BeginForm(new {name = "form1" })
```

and then use this :

```
onclick="document.form1.submit();"
```

But is it possible to use the same thing in the Url.Action instead of the onclick because i need the function in the controller?

Cheers

Comment: Can I ask why you need to put the submit button outside of a form?

Comment: @ChrisHardie Also, if you want to submit button outside a form then why use Html.BeginForm?

Comment: Styling issues, I need to close a div before the button and since it's not possible to close a div inside a form..

Comment: @Biplov13 What do you sugest instead?

Comment: @JaperTIA Why do you think you cannot close a div? You could wrap your entire page in a form and it would be completely valid.

Comment: @ChrisHardie because the opening tag is opened outside the form and should be closed inside..

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Please ensure your markup is valid: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: why dont you specify the action and controller inside the html.begin form method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#sendButton').click(function(){
  $('form[name=yourFormName]').setAttrib('action','actionName');
  $('form[name=yourFormName]').submit();
});
```

Or try other way:

```
$('#sendButton').on('click', function () {
            var yourData = { tag1 : $('#tag1').val(), tag2 : $('#tag2').val() /*etc..*/ };
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: yourData ,
                    success: function (response) {
                    //sended..
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                    //not sended..
                    },
                });
});
```

Comment: Which value do i need to set on button because it's not launching this function..

Comment: I am sorry, can not understand you well. That function should launch normally. Or I didn't get what you want ecaxtly